# How I can I have a separate variation field in Commerce 2?

Tags: 8, entities, commerce, display-suite

I have a Commerce 2 website, where my product display page is a two column layout through display suite.

In 1 column I would like to display the picture of the product variation and, in the other column want to display product description, add to cart button, and price.

[image]

Under product type **Manage Display**, I only see one variation field which have images, price and add to cart widget.

[image]

In Commerce 1, these used to be separate product variation type fields but in Commerce 2, I do not see how to accomplish this.

How I can I have a separate variation field in Commerce 2 with Display Suite?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have rewrite the question to explain the issue properly. Kindly consider reopen it.

Comment: Due to limitations in Display Suite, you currently can't use it with Commerce. See https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2723689

Comment: @kiamlaluno It was really helpful. The plugin mentioned in that thread did the trick https://www.drupal.org/project/ds_chains though it's currently in alpha version